# Mongoose with unique boolean of true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know how to set a string to be unique on my schema like this:

```
string: { type: String, unique: true }
```

but is there a way to have unique boolean with true value on an object and rest with false(set by default)? What I need is: If I try to save an object with true value and one with true already exists error is returned.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using MongoDB's support for [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/) that was added in 3.2.

```
var mySchema = new Schema({ oneTrue: Boolean });
mySchema.index({oneTrue: 1}, {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {oneTrue: true}});
```

This will create the unique index on the `oneTrue` field only where its value is `true`. That way, multiple docs with a `false` value are allowed, but only one where it's `true`.

Comment: what if I would like to have 1 `oneTrue: true` for all documents that have the same eg: `customerId`?

Comment: Should just need to change it to `mySchema.index({customerId: 1, oneTrue: 1}, ...` @MendiSterenfeld

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

If you look at the [Mongoose Documentation for Unique Constraints](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique), you can see it:

> Declares an unique index.

You would need to implement a custom read/write process in order to achieve what you want.