# How can I ensure an item in a mongoose collection is the only one with a boolean flag field set to true?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a use case where at most one item in a collection needs to be flagged as a special case item.

For a contrived, simple example, let's say I have a model called `Category` who's schema has a boolean field called `isUncategorized`.

Only a single Category can be marked as `isUncategorized` which could be used as a catch all if a child is not assigned to any other category. A unique index won't work because all other categories will have `isUncategorized = false` or no `isUncategorized` property.

My thought was to add a custom validator on this property which uses the `Category` model to check for any other items with this property set to `true`. However, I'm not certain how (or if it's even possible) to access the `Category` model from within a validator in the schema definition.

Is it appropriate to access this model in it's own schema definition? Or is there perhaps a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Mongoose with unique boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407959/mongoose-with-unique-boolean-of-true).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Step**

When creating Category model, set `isUncategorized` field to `false` as default value.

**2. Step**

Ensure in the backend that no one can specify that value when creating new Category (but the default one will be used).

**3. Step**

Go in database and manually change `isUncategorized` field for relevant Category to `true`.

This is also a good practice for User Authorization, when all users are automatically created as basic user, and if you want to give someone an admin privilegies, you will ensure that no code can do that (because of the security), but you go in database an manually change relevant documents.